# What is the best approach to deal with page refresh in a Single Page Application?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

I used to build websites using Java/Spring that there will be a controller to capture the request for a specific URL (e.g. mydomain.com/xyz) so that user can hit the refresh button in the browser and the page is still showing. But with Single Page Application since all pages are loaded all at once, what happens when a user hits the refresh button on one of the pages there? The browser will try to send a request to the backend but the backend knows nothing about the specific URL, what is the best way to deal with such situation?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=single+page+application+routing&oq=single+page+application+routing&aqs=chrome..69i57.10262j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest case, you have your web server configured to deliver the HTML of your web application at any URL.

For example:

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/foo
http://example.com/foo/some/deeply/nested?link=true
```

Would all return the same HTML, which loads the same javascript which launches your application.

Then your single page app uses routing, where it looks at the current url and decides what component to display based on that.

[React Router](https://reactrouter.com/) is a popular choice for this. You setup a series of paths that are rendered by components with something like:

```
<Route path="/books/:id" component={BookPage} />
<Route path="/users" component={UsersPage} />
<Route path="/safety" component={SafetyPage} />
```

When when your app starts up, and `/books/123` is in the URL, then `BookPage` is rendered.

---

To take that further, you can have the server pre-render your components and deliver your page the way that your frontend application would have rendered it. You still have routing as above, but now the application "rehydrates" that HTML as the basis for your UI. This helps with loads times, since the entire code of your app doesn't need to load to see content, as well as allowing search engines to index your content (since they don't execute javascript).

This is a bit more complicated, but if you're curious, [Next.JS](https://nextjs.org/) is a popular choice.